# How can I make an Avalonia XAML TextBlock bold according to a binding value?

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui

I am using AvaloniaUI to make a list of labels (TextBlocks). I want some of them to be bold, according to the underlying data status. Can someone point me in the direction of how to make a TextBlock in a DataTemplate bold or not according to a binding value please?

Code of the item:

```
    public FontWeight DisplayWeight() => !IsBold ? FontWeight.Black : FontWeight.Bold;
```

Template code:

```
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="{Binding DisplayWeight}" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Putting in a hard coded weight works.

So I tried a style:

```
    public string DisplayClass() => IsBold ? "h1" : "p";

    <TextBlock Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Classes="{Binding DisplayClass}" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

That gets me an error at startup: Unable to cast object of type 'Avalonia.Data.Binding' to type 'System.String'
I presume it hasn't processed the binding at that point.

What is the right path please?

Comment: Are you sure that you've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and are properly triggering PropertyChanged event for DisplayWeight property?

Comment: Nothing has changed here, this is in the creation at this point. However, if I need to do more to make it work, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the following XAML line:

```
 <TextBlock Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="{Binding DisplayWeight}" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

worked when the following lines were applied to the object I wanted to display:

```
    private FontWeight _displayWeight = FontWeight.Normal;
    private bool _isBold;

    public FontWeight DisplayWeight
    {
        get { return _displayWeight; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this._displayWeight, value); }
    }

    public bool IsBold
    {
        get => _isBold;
        set
        {
            _isBold = value;
            DisplayWeight = _isBold ? FontWeight.Bold : FontWeight.Normal;
        }
    }
```